# How can I highlight search terms using animated color change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I have a word cloud and I want to pick a few unique pre-defined words from it and smoothly change their color. Basically I want to do this,

```
// font color animation
$(".second a").hover(function() {
$(this).animate({ color: "#00eeff" }, 400);
},function() {
$(this).animate({ color: "#FFFFFF" }, 500);
});
```

but instead of hover being the trigger I just want to have a setTimeout function trigger the change. How can I do that? Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Not clear what the problem is. Why isn't setTimeout working?

Comment: You cannot natively animate color without: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want either, but all the same I just spent fifteen minutes of my life I'm not getting back writing an example on how to do something similar (uses UI for color animation).

```
var words = ['Lorem', 'Tatum'],
    color = 'red',
    elems = [],
    T1 = setInterval(randomRed, 1000);

$('#yourelements').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == words[0] || $(this).text() == words[1]) {
        elems.push($(this));
    }
});

//I cut this down from the example in the fiddle, elements could be filtered in the below function instead?

function randomRed() {
    $(elems).each(function() {
        var r1 = Math.random()*500,
            r2 = Math.random()*1000;
        $(this).delay(r1).animate({color: color}, r2, function() {
            var r3 = Math.random()*500,
                r4 = Math.random()*1000;
            $(this).delay(r3).animate({color: 'black'}, r4);
        });
    });
}
```

Here's a [fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/nzG8x/3/)

Comment: Just a note: The jQuery docs for `.animate()` link to a plugin that is 16KB un-minified that does the same color animations that jQuery UI does ( https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color ). You can download a version of jQuery UI that is pretty close in size but you have to de-select everything except for the "Effects Core" (even the jQuery UI Core).

Comment: Good note Jasper, was actually going to mention that but forgot. This basicly just shows how to select elements from the containing words in the most basic way, and how to do some random color animations. jQuery's contains or filter methods could also be used to find the right elements, and from there it should be easy enough making them change color.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could actually use a setTimeout...if that's the kind of trigger you're looking for :). Also you would need to iterate the collection using something like jQuery each

It would be something like this...

```
var someMilliseconds = 500;
setTimeout(function() {
   // font color animation
   $(".second a").animate({ 'color' : '#00eeff' }, 400);
}, someMilliseconds );
```

I think that's what you are asking? :)

Comment: Take another look at your code, it doesn't quite make sense. The `.each()` function is being passed two functions: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Ya, you're right, I made a mistake. I'll fix it. I guess I wasn't sure what he/she is trying to do. Two different animates right? I'll fix the code.

Comment: Actually...you need a plugin for 'color' as well. Sorry, this was a sloppy response :).

Comment: Here, I wrote this a while ago to demo a bug with color change that occurs when you don't have the browser tab focused [http://jsfiddle.net/farina/DjRyw/]. It's not exactly what you're doing, but it is roughly the same idea.

Comment: If you are setting a single `setTimeout` then you won't be toggling anything, you can just call `.animate()` once to animate the color change after a delay (`someMilliseconds` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery documentation for `.animate()`:

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,
>   except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be
>   animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height,
>   or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the
>   [jQuery.Color()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin is used). Property values are treated as a
>   number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be
>   specified where applicable.

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/animate/*

Short answer: You need a plugin to animate colors with jQuery.

Here is a demo using the plugin that the jQuery docs suggests to use and a `setInterval` call: http://jsfiddle.net/f4PEL/1/

Also, if you want to continuously animate the color of the links then take a look at `setInterval()`, it will run on an interval rather than once. You can also mimic this interval behavior by recursively calling the same function with a `setTimeout()`.

Docs for `setInterval()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval